# For what n can a cube be partitioned into n similar, mutually non-congruent cuboids?

Tags: co.combinatorics

This is the 3D version of the 2D question "For what n can a square be partitioned into $n$ similar, mutually non-congruent rectangles?", for which the answer is all $n >= 3$.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, but it's well-known that a cube can't be partitioned into  finitely many smaller distinct cubes. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squaring_the_square#Cubing_the_cube

Comment: Does taking the solution for the square and just turning each $a \times b$ rectangle into an $a \times b \times 1$ cuboid not work? Do you have a reference for this 2D version?

Comment: @Nate: this sounds as though you would have a problem with the *similar* part?

Comment: @Nate - No. For example if you take the unique solution to the 2D version for $n=3$, the rectangles that partition the unit square have side-lengths $(1,\rho^{-2})$, $(\rho^{-1},\rho^{-3})$, and $(\rho^{-3},\rho^{-5})$, giving cuboids $(1,1,\rho^{-2})$, $(1,\rho^{-1},\rho^{-3})$, and $(1, \rho^{-3},\rho^{-5})$, which are not similar. To the second question: yes: the accepted answer to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/371035/for-what-n-and-t-can-a-square-be-partitioned-into-n-similar-rectangles-in-t-cong).

Comment: @GerryMyerson - But that does make it impossible to do this using cuboids with side-lengths all a rational proportion of the cube's side-length. Otherwise one could break each cuboid into cubes, and if any cubes were duplicated then break those cubes into cuboids and then into cubes, repeating as necessary until all smaller cubes were mutually non-congruent, thereby cubing the cube.